# Is it possible to check sms verification at verification-check-beta two times?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, verify

I have a scenario:

- servers sends sms code to user using verification-check-beta
- users submits sms code
- several independent server instances verify sms several times using `sms` code and/or `VerificationSid`

`verify sms several times` - the first one instance would use smsCode + VerificationSid and other params. Other instances would check if specific `VerificationSid` was verified.

Then code or verification status should be expired (10 min b default, right)?

Is it do-able?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What do you mean the server should verify the SMS several times? Why would you want to do the same verification more than once? Have you tried implementing anything yet?

Comment: I've added more details. My usecase: Imagine I have several independent server instances and all of them know that user requested sms to confirm some operation. These instances know sms code VerificationSid. They need independently contact Twilio and check if provided sms is correct or if verification was recently confirmed.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn’t rely on Twilio to verify the same code over and over. In fact, it’s a security risk to allow the same code to be used more than once. Instead, I would have your user submit the code to an authorisation server and have that server return something like a signed JWT, that you could then use as a token to be used and verified across the other servers.

Comment: The problem is a bit different. These server instances want to check if verification for specific code was passed or not. They don’t try to use it for verifying different operation. Imagine I don’t trust server so I have several indentical instances asking Twillio if it got correct code for specific verification or not. Even if one of instances is compromised another instances would still provide correct  verification result form Twillio

Comment: I don’t understand why you wouldn’t trust your own, but this sort of thing is still a job for your own auth server. In my opinion you should verify with Twilio once and then have the other servers verify with this auth server.